Nextjs dynamic loading mui icon failed
I tried
"use client"
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';

const DynamicIcon = ({ iconName }) => {
  const IconComponent = dynamic(() =>
    import(`@mui/icons-material/${iconName}`).then((mod) => mod.default),
  );

  return <IconComponent />;
};

export default DynamicIcon;

then on page
<DynamicIcon iconName="FollowTheSignsTwoTone" />

Error: Module not found: Can't resolve '@mui/icons-material'
I also tried something like this but no lucky
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const DynamicIcon = ({ iconName }) => {
  const [IconComponent, setIconComponent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadIcon = async () => {
      try {
        const { default: ImportedIcon } = await import(
          `@mui/icons-material/${iconName}`
        );
        setIconComponent(() => ImportedIcon);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error loading icon: ${iconName}`, error);
      }
    };

    loadIcon();
  }, [iconName]);

  if (!IconComponent) return null;

  return <IconComponent />;
};

export default function MyComponent() {
  const icon = 'FollowTheSignsTwoTone';

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dynamic Icon Import</h1>
      <DynamicIcon iconName={icon} />
    </div>
  );
}

Its can be load when i use import FollowTheSignsTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FollowTheSignsTwoTone';
I tried searching but couldn't find the answer. How can I dynamically insert these ICONs?

I believe , the next/dynamic method you tried initially has issues with module resolution when used with certain setups.
DynamicIcon.js
"use client";
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const DynamicIcon = ({ iconName }) => {
  const [IconComponent, setIconComponent] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const loadIcon = async () => {
      try {
        const { default: ImportedIcon } = await import(
          `@mui/icons-material/${iconName}`
        );
        setIconComponent(() => ImportedIcon);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(`Error loading icon: ${iconName}`, error);
      }
    };

    loadIcon();
  }, [iconName]);

  if (!IconComponent) return null;

  return <IconComponent />;
};

export default DynamicIcon;

MyComponent.js
import DynamicIcon from './DynamicIcon'; // Adjust path as necessary

export default function MyComponent() {
  const icon = 'FollowTheSignsTwoTone'; // Ensure this is a valid icon name

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Dynamic Icon Import</h1>
      <DynamicIcon iconName={icon} />
    </div>
  );
}


Thanks, I tried your method, but the error show up, ./node_modules/@mui/icons-material/CHANGELOG.md
Module parse failed: Unexpected character ' ' (1:1)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders

Versions

|
| ## v5.15.20, i have no idea why its so hard to load as dynamic :(

By any chance you didn't install mui icons?
It's a standalone package
npm install @mui/icons-material


I have already installed, its work if i import like this import FollowTheSignsTwoToneIcon from '@mui/icons-material/FollowTheSignsTwoTone';
